# Is there a provision to Sign document through API call

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement where I need to get the document signed and saved in db. We do not want to get this done by sending the mail and then the user will click on the link and completed the signing process through DocuSign UI. We want to make the signing process invisible to the end user. So is there a way where we cna get the document signed through code.

Comment: You want to sign a document on behalf of your signer without signer being aware that a document was signed without his/her consent?isn't that illegal? Or do you want Signer to come to your App to do the signing and does not have to move out of your App to complete the signing process?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to electronically sign a document programmatically as long as you have a clear legal agreement with the person whose signature will be added to the document.

DocuSign supports this use case through the DocuSign Signature Appliance.

- [Overview](https://www.docusign.com/products/signature-appliance)
- [API information](https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api)
- [Developer Sandbox signup](https://go.docusign.com/signup/dsa-developer/) (no charge)